# How to erase slug parent from breadcrumbs links in Yoast

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, breadcrumbs, yoast

I have this Breadcrumbs structure making with Yoast Seo

Home  >> Parks >>  Big Park

If you press in Parks, the url target in Parks is: https://www.home.com/listing-category/parks/

I want, that the url target there will be: https://www.home.com/parks/

Is there any method to make this change of url (maybe any function to put in functions.php file)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it :)

With this function in fuctions.php

```
    add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'yoast_seo_breadcrumb_append_link' );
    function yoast_seo_breadcrumb_append_link( $links ) {
    global $post;
    $my_slug = (string) $links[1][term]->slug;
    switch ($my_slug){
        case "parks":
            $breadcrumb[] = array(
                'url' => site_url( '/parks/' ),
                'text' => 'Parks',
                'title' => 'Parks of my city',
            );
            array_splice( $links, 1, -2, $breadcrumb );
            unset($links[2]);
            break;
    }

    return $links;
}
```